# Problem with adding item to array in an Ordered Set

Tags: java, arrays, set, addition, sortedset

I am having trouble adding an item to my array set, it should be ordered in ascending order and for some reason I just get to add it and it does not order it.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean add(AnyType x){
    if(this.contains(x))
        return false;
    else if(this.isEmpty()){
        items[theSize]=x;
        theSize++;
        return true;
    }
    else{
    if( theSize == items.length )
        this.grow();
    //Here goes code for adding
    /*AnyType[] newItems = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[items.length];
    newItems = items;
    for(int i=0;i<theSize;i++)
        if(items[i].compareTo(x)>0){
            newItems[i]=x;
            newItems[i+1]=items[i];
            for(int j=i+1;j<theSize;j++)
                newItems[j]=items[i];
            items = newItems;
            theSize++;
            return true;
        }

    //*/
    items[theSize]=x; //*/
    theSize++;
    return true;
    }
}
```

The method should not allow an item to repeat so if you try to add something that is already in there, it should return false. If the array is empty just add to items[0] and then I tried to create a new array and once you find an item bigger than the one I'm inputing copy everything into a new array, add the new value, and just add the rest and then make `items = newItems;` but it did not work. I have been trying for a couple hours now so I just decided to ask for help.
I have my SortedSet class defined like this:

```
public class SortedSet<AnyType extends Comparable> implements Set<AnyType>
{
    private AnyType[] items;
    private int theSize;
    public SortedSet(){
        theSize = 0;
        items = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[5];
    }
```

I know there are other ways to do this like using TreeMap but it has to be done as an array.

Thanks

Comment: So, you tagged your question with [sortedset], which sounds like you already know about `SortedSet`. In fact, `TreeSet` or the like would be the correct way to implement what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see where you are writing the previous values?

Try something like this in the last else.

```
            theSize++;
            AnyType[] newItems = new AnyType[theSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < theSize-1; i++)
                if(items[i].compareTo(x) > 0)
                {
                    newItems[i] = x;
                    newItems[i + 1] = items[i];
                    for(int j = i + 2; j < theSize; j++)
                        newItems[j] = items[j-1];
                    items = newItems;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    newItems[i] = items[i];
            newItems[theSize-1] = x;
            items = newItems;
            return true;
```

Since I already coded it to make sure it works fine, here is a sample working on Strings. I focused here only on correct adding. The other issues important for the OP were omitted.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OrderingAddTest
{
    static int theSize = 0;
    static String[] items = new String[theSize];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        add("a");
        add("e");
        add("d");
        add("b");
        add("c");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items)+"\n; items.length="+items.length);
    }

    private static boolean add(String x)
    {
        theSize++;
        String[] newItems = new String[theSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < theSize - 1; i++)
            if(items[i].compareTo(x) > 0)
            {
                newItems[i] = x;
                newItems[i + 1] = items[i];
                for(int j = i + 2; j < theSize; j++)
                    newItems[j] = items[j - 1];
                items = newItems;
                return true;
            }
            else
                newItems[i] = items[i];
        newItems[theSize - 1] = x;
        items = newItems;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited it to my program following the same structure and I ad 5, 6 and 7 and then I go to add a three and I just get 3 3 3 null

Comment: @fgualda87  please do check if you have the current version as I have edited it slightly. Plus you are sure you are increasing the size accordingly?

Comment: @fgualda87 check out if the for loop with j's you have something like this newItems[j] = items[j-1]; because you had i there. instead of j-1 thus you had the same value all the time. Plus the j loop should start from i+2 as at i+1 you already add something.

Comment: @Boro Yes, I am getting a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at that line newItems[j]=items[j-1];

Comment: @Boro why did you add theSize++ at the beginning?

Comment: @fgualda87 OK this one should be final there was also one more problem. But now I increase the size at first. Then the first for loop we iterate over items thus i<theSize-1 then for with j we iterate over newItems thus j<theSize.

Comment: Because lots of errors I did in this sample code were cause that I had to think about theSize in too many places thus I made errors. And in this else you know that theSize will have to be increased anyway right?

Comment: Yeah but it would make more sense just to use theSize plus one and increment it at the end that just start by increasing theSize.

Comment: But this way you would have to have it in two places one if you find some x, and second if you don't which is generally bad to have the same code in two places.

Comment: I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 in line   newItems[theSize-1] =x;

Comment: @fgualda87  Did you increased the newItems size, or as I did it increased theSize by 1 at start? If so then theSize -1 should exist since this is the last index.

Comment: I was increasing theSize at the end again so it would give me an out of bounds exception.

Comment: @fgualda87 good that it helped. Just in case since I tested in myself on Strings I added my sample. Have fun.

Comment: @Boro I'm so lazy, and if is possible, then I using Arrays.sort(items, Collections.reverseOrder()); Arrays.sort(items);  that allows index from -> to, with or without Comparator ... +1

Comment: @Boro I was thinking and if I add an item in a for loop like set1.add("" + i); when I want to print it out it doesn't order it like it should... It goes from 1 straight to 10, 11,...,19,2,20,21,...,29,3,30, etc what do you think it could be??

Comment: @mKorbel nice very nice idea in fact the solution you are suggesting wouldn't by significantly less efficient, I think. Anyway you must create a larger array add element. Then iterate over it. I guess it depends all on how efficient would be the sorting algorithm. Plus the code would be more elastic in a way that straight forward you would be able to reverse the order if you ever needed it, as you show.  Thanks.

Comment: @fgualda87 the reason why it behaves like this is very simple that is how Strings are compared lexicographically. Not as integers, so this is all fine.

Comment: @Boro is there anything I can do to fix it? maybe implementing my own compareTo() method?

Comment: But why do you mind that? Of coarse you could do it by extending your algorithm and treating all numbers which you have in the items arrays as Numbers and not Strings. E.g. try (if you want to include all Numbers) `Double.parseDouble(string);` it throws exception if the string is not a Double number. If it didn't throw exception then it is a number but if it did it is a String. Then instead using `String.compareTo(x) > 0` you must use `number > x`.

Comment: so I would have to create an if statement and if throws an exception is a string and if not is a number? I only need to work with whole numbers but declared as strings hence I need it to sort the strings as well :/

Comment: like string with integers like for(int i=0;i<50;i++){set1.add("" + i);}

Comment: @fgualda87 yea something as you are saying just treat numbers as numbers and Strings as Strings as you add them to the structure and all will be cool.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a native Java class that have theses features: java.util.TreeSet.

In a Set, the same element cannot appear twice. The "add" method returns a boolean: true if the item was added, false if it was already in the set.

TreeSet is an implementation of "SortedSet", that maintain an order on the elements. Your items only have to implement "Comparable".

Comment: Yes but I have to define it myself

Comment: I know there are other ways to do this, but it has to be this way, that's why I'm asking

Comment: If you have to implement the same feature, you can look at the source code of TreeSet (source are available in the JDK): you will have indications about the native implementation and you'll can get inspiration for your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your items is of the same size as of items, it should be Size+1

I guess you got a problem here

for(int j=i+ 1; j < theSize;j++)

newItems[j]=items[i];

here j is incrementing for sure, but there is no increment operation given for i, so all the newitems in this loop are being assigned the same value

---

EDIT :

```
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < theSize+1 ; i++)
    if(items[i].compareTo(x)>0){
    newItems[i]=x;

    for(;i<theSize + 1; i++)
     newItems[i]=items[i-1];
```

### : do whatever next.

EDIT 2 :

U are doing a wrong thing here also,

items = newItems;

and the previous assigning statement (newItems=items)

you can't equate them as they are not of same size, you can do that if you use Pointer, (Using Pointers here will make this task A LOT easier,)

Comment: But the rest should be done by the other for loop before this one, that one increments i, no?

Comment: NO, the loop that increments i works only till the if statement is not true, coz after that you return true before the i could iterate to next...Check the edit.

Comment: @TarunG what are you using for the size of the new array? AnyType[] newItems = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[theSize];? just theSize?

Comment: See, whenever you are writing some code, see what your needs are, Here you need to ADD one more element , so The size Must increment by 1.

Comment: I know pointers would make this a lot easier, but thats for ArrayLists not arrays

Comment: Okk,, so where you are encountering the problem now?

Comment: I got it right from Boro, you were close tho, thank you very much!